# Kendo upload change color when hover with file

Tags: kendo-upload

I'm using the Kendo Upload-control to upload files.
When I hover over the button, it changes color.
How can I achieve the same thing, when I hover over the button while dragging a file to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can hook on **dragenter** and **dragleave** jQuery events of the upload input element and change the color of the button as for example it is done in this [dojo page](http://dojo.telerik.com/@zdravkov/ebasa).